# React JSX in JSON array of object map

Tags: arrays, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

A JSON array of icons with names is available. I want to map JSX but nothing shows as JSX element (icons) in the output, the code uses Material-UI elements and Icons:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Box, Paper, Typography} from '@mui/material';
import WorkIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Work';
import Settings from '@mui/icons-material/Settings';
const iconsSet = [
  {
    name: 'WorkIcon',
    icon: ()=> (<WorkIcon/>),   {/* JSX as fields value */}
  },
  {
    name: 'Settings',
    icon: () =>(<Settings/>),
  }
];
export default function Icons() {
  return (
    <Box>
      {iconsSet.map(({name,icon})=>(
        <Paper>
          {icon} {/* Nothing Shows  */}
          <Typography>{name}</Typography>
        </Paper>
      ))}
    </Box>
    );
}
```

[link to Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/icons-material-demo-forked-hp1n18?file=/demo.js)

Comment: Are there any errors in the console or any other information to help debug this?

Comment: Everything looks good, but nothing shows

Answer (score 2):

You have to name JSX elements with capital first letter, try `Icon` in the object key:

```js
const iconsSet = [
  {
    name: 'WorkIcon',
    Icon: ()=> (<WorkIcon/>),   {/* JSX as fields value */}
  },
  {
    name: 'Settings',
    Icon: () =>(<Settings/>),
  }
];
```

And then use it in JSX inside the `map()` like this:

```js
<Box>
  {iconsSet.map(({name,Icon})=>(
    <Paper>
      <Icon />
      <Typography>{name}</Typography>
    </Paper>
  ))}
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Box, Paper, Typography} from '@mui/material';
import WorkIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Work';
import Settings from '@mui/icons-material/Settings';
const iconsSet = [
  {
    name: 'WorkIcon',
    icon: ()=> (<WorkIcon/>),   {/* JSX as fields value */}
  },
  {
    name: 'Settings',
    icon: () =>(<Settings/>),
  }
];
export default function Icons() {
  return (
    <Box>
      {iconsSet.map(({name,icon})=>(
        <Paper>
          {icon()} {/* here is the change  */}
          <Typography>{name}</Typography>
        </Paper>
      ))}
    </Box>
    );
}
```